# ConversionService with mvc annotation driven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I've enabled **mvc annotation driven** on my project adding to **spring servlet xml** the following configs:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
           <bean class="com.test.WebArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
             <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

After this changes the jsp page below stopped working:

```xml
<spring:bind path="list">
    <form:select path="maxFrequency">
        <form:options items="${status.value}"/>
    </form:select>
</spring:bind>
<spring:message code="test.property" />
```

Namely as result I have:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [java.lang.String] is not valid for option items
```

My controller and form:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String show(@ModelAttribute("form") AccessForm form, Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException {
    AccessSettings settings = getAccessSettings();
    form.setAlertSettings(settings.getAlertSettings());
    form.setMaxFrequency(settings.getMaxFrequency());
    return "page";
}

public class AccessForm{

    public List<Long> getList() {
        // some custom logic that generate long items
    }
}
```

I've tried to debug this and found that annotation driven enabled **ConversionService** that try to convert bean properties using formatters from class above.

Can someone explain in which way I can disable the **default formatters** or could you suggest some workarounds to achive the same goals on jsp page.

Comment: What is `status`? What is `status.value`?

Comment: Actually it's a some value from list. Please find the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.6/taglib/tag/BindTag.html for relevant information.

Comment: shouldn't items be a list rather than a single string?

Comment: Yes it should be, but ConversionService formatter converts it to string as I mentioned in the question. So the question is how to avoid this transformation.

Comment: Why would the `ConversionService` convert a collection to a `String`? Are you asking for a `String`?

Comment: So, I have the list of elements that I am going to show in the combo box. But unfortunatly the collection converted to string. So as result the mentioned exception appears. I've dubbuged AbstractPropertyBindingResult from 108 to 128 lines where magic is happens. I have no any ideas why it's work in this way.

Comment: Please show us a full example that we can reproduce. **Also**, what do you expect `items="${status.value}` to do?

Comment: I've added controllers and form to question. Actually items="${status.value} has been initial implementation, the idea is to show all elements and which is selected. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What Spring version are you using? Also, I don't think `spring:bind` is meant to be used to bind a request attribute like you've shown since you could simply do `options="${list}"`.